# Scatter plot with two data sets

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

The following code plots two lines. Instead I need dots without lines:

```
plt.plot(y1, marker='o', color='b')
plt.plot(y2, marker='o', color='r')
plt.show()
```

What should I change to get proper result?

Comment: have you not looked through the examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `plt.scatter` to get a scatter plot.

```
import matplotlib.pylot as plt

plt.scatter(x, y1)
plt.scatter(x, y2)
plt.show()
```

You would set `x` to be a list containing the corresponding x axis values for your series. For instance, if your data start from x=0 and go up by one, you could use `x = range(len(y1))` as your x axis series.

Comment: How can I retrieve these x values?

Comment: edited to include an example of how to set your `x` series

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

```
plt.plot(y1, marker='o', linestyle=None, color='b')
plt.plot(y2, marker='o', linestyle=None, color='r')
plt.show()
```

EDIT: the `linestyle=None` raises an Error. You can use `linestyle=''` or directly:

```
plt.plot(y1,'bo')
plt.plot(y2,'ro')
plt.show()
```

should work.

Comment: It says: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Comment: @elsherbini sorry I've just edited the post I didn't notice your comment, thanks!